# How to get `git add` to list files that's staged

Tags: git, git-add

How do I get git to echo what files that are being staged during `git add` command?

Something like this...

```
> git add app/
app/index.html added
> _
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
git add -v
```

(or `--verbose`, same thing).  For whatever reasons, `git rm` is always `-v` (in effect—it doesn't actually have a `-v` option) and requires `-q` to make it quiet, while `git add` is never verbose and requires `-v` to make it loud.  (Or, with `-n` it doesn't actually add but is verbose.)

Comment: Are there no configuration to turn it on by default?

Comment: No, and, the asymmetry with add vs rm not taking the same flags bugs me too.